# WP Обновление данных в БД по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Подскажите, как реализовать обновление данных в кастомной таблице БД WP по нажатию на кнопку. Вот простой пример:

Есть `HTML` в админке плагина

```
<p>Tournaments are empty</p><button id="btn_update" class="btn_update">Update Sports Result</button>
```

Вот скрипт который по идеи должен обновить два поля uploadData.php:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_updateDB', 'updateDataBase' );
function updateDataBase(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'sports_viewer', // указываем таблицу
        array('json' => $_POST['text']),
        array('object_last_modified' => 1 ),

        array( '%s' ),
        array( '%d' )
    );

    wp_die();
}
```

Вот файл отправки через `AJAX`

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#btn_update').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'updateDB',
                text: "this is test text", /// Тут так надо передавать значение в php переменную $text?
            },

            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                $('#btn_update').text('Обновление базы, сек...');
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                $('#btn_update').text('Отправить');
                alert( data );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

В ячейку `json` - хочу отправить текст. В ячейку `object_last_modified` - записать время последнего обновления (если оно было успешным). Как это связывается в `php`?

Comment: Если я Вас верно понял, то для `object_last_modified` можете использовать [current_time()](https://wp-kama.com/function/current_time). На счет формы, то она здесь не обязательна в принципе, Вы там абсолютно никаких данных не передаете, так-то можете аякс привязать к клику на кнопку и на бекенде в аякс хендлере сделать все что Вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно какой-то пример вменяемый? Будет ли добавлено время если добавление первого параметра поломается (пример очень большой массив данных) ? (или если хоть один параметр не прошел, то обновление не произойдет?)

Comment: *В ячейку object_last_modified - записать время последнего обновления (если оно было успешным).* В MySQL есть автообновлемые поля времени. Которые при обновлении автоматически получают текущую метку времени. Такое поле вообще не нужно указывать в запросе. Читать [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: Спасибо, вроде я его задал - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Только не знаю как опробовать. Как происходит связка php с запросом... как произвести инициализацию функции?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: @KAGG Design Спасибо за пример, но это немного не то. Хотелось бы увидеть как происходит обновление кастомных таблиц в БД, а тут это не раскрывается. Как происходят ajax запросы именно в БД WP.

Comment: Не важно, какой php код выполняется по ajax. Я вам показал, как делается сам вызов ajax. Далее, в своем php коде вам надо произвести запись в базу примерно так, как и написано в вопросе - через $wpdb.

Comment: @KAGG Design спасибо, переписал через отправку ajax-ом. (код поменял) Вот только не могу понять. Оно мне возвращает ошибку 400. Хотя в Response сервера 0. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 `action` должен быть в объекте `data`. Ну и в `$text` в функции `updateDataBase()`, как и `$wpdb` не должны быть параметрами. `global $wpdb;` логичнее объявить внутри функции, а $text принять из `$_POST`.

Comment: Можете использовать либо `$_POST['text']` и потом очистить данные, либо сразу сделать `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'text', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)`. В аяксе знак доллара в названии ключа `text` объекта дата ни к чему.

Comment: @Simon Спасибо за замечание. Код заменил, но всё равно не работает. Ошибка 400. Может тут ещё что-то по безопасности необходимо передавать ? Или заголовки какие?

Comment: Было бы хорошо использовать вп нонсы, но Вы іх не используете, потому проблема явно не с этим, ну и тогда было бы `403 Forbidden`. 400 обычно когда имя экшна не совпадает. А где находится этот Ваш скрипт `uploadData.php`? + уберите параметр из `updateDataBase( $text )` + у Вас два открывающих php тега (может Вы конечно тут при редактировании задублировали случайно) + уберите `if( ! empty($wpdb->error) ) wp_die( $wpdb->error );` оно там не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Всё равно не срабатывает. Залил сюда плагин, https://github.com/BlackStar1991/WordPress-Plugins  пожете посмотреть?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139972/discussion-between-simon-and-blackstar1991).